# IOS 12 didn't receiving app push notification only if Iphone has been reset as new

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios12

We are facing some problem about our hibryd app, in Android it works fine, in ios 11 and below our app is working. If user has an Iphone with IOS 11 and update to IOS 12 app still works, but if user reset his/her Iphone and then install the app it just doesn't send push notifications, all the notification settings are ok, this just don't have any behaviour when receiving a new message.

Comment: How do you register for the push notification token?  You should do it each time your app launches as it can change. It will definitely change if the device is reset.

Comment: @Paulw11 I save in a table device token, and then when I need to send a push I use this token to send a message to person. Every each time I save token from users device;